# No linebreaks in vcalendar file when echoing values with PHP

Tags: php, icalendar, vcalendar, vcal

I have a vcalendar file. It works perfect if i type it between php tags like this

```
?>


BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20110422
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20120529
DTSTAMP:20120529T124028Z
UID:7a6db67f3edff4729956c47ec@calendarlabs.com
CREATED:20111213T123901Z
DESCRIPTION:Visit http://www.calendarlabs.com/holidays/ to know more about New Year's Day and for any other calendar needs.
LAST-MODIFIED:20111213T123901Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:New Year's Day
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT


 <?php

 echo :
```

However, soon as i put it in echo statements like so:

```
 echo "BEGIN:VEVENT";
```

then it doesn't work. I have tried adding \n, 
 everything.

Also doesnt work if i do something like:

```
   DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:<?php echo $date; ?>
```

Can anybody else see a solution here?

Comment: if you use echo, then it should be within `<? ?>` shouldn't it?

Comment: What's the difference in **the final output**?

Comment: There is no line breaks when i echo it out with php. only if i type it outside the tags.

Comment: heredoc syntax may preserve the characters you are having issues with. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: What is the extension of the file?

Comment: Have you added this extension to your php.ini and/or htaccess ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PHP's closing tag eats whitespace following it.](http://brian.moonspot.net/php-history-newline-closing-tag)  If you want to preserve newlines when outputting with PHP, you will need to do one of the following:

- Output the newline character explicitly:

  ```
  DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:<?php echo $date, PHP_EOL; ?>
  ```
- Use [heredoc syntax](http://php.net/heredoc):

  ```
  echo <<<END
  BEGIN:VEVENT
  ...
  DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:$date
  END;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Your web server probably does not recognize .ics file as a script, therefore it does not send the file to the hypertext processor (php) to process the instructions inside php tags. You need to tell your web server to treat this as a php file. Tutorial for adding custom extension could be found here: http://creativebriefing.com/custom-file-extensions/.